# Jetty ServletTester throws SecurityException

Tags: java, jetty, securityexception, jar-signing

When I put the following dependency (and all of its transitive deps as well) on my classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
</dependency>
```

And run this JUnit test:

```
public class MySimpleTest {
    private ServletTester tester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        tester = new ServletTester();
        tester.contextPath = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/location";
        tester.addServlet(MyAppMockEndpoint.class, "/address/*");
        tester.start();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        tester.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Dummy assertion that is always true, just to prove its not
        // my code throwing the exception.
        Assert.assertTrue(System.currentTimeMillis() > 0L);
    }

    public class MyAppMockEndpoint extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().println(provideJson())
            response.getWriter().flush()
        }

        public String provideJson() {
            return "{ \"id\": 5, \"fizz\": \"true\", \"buzz\": \"false\" }";
        }
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.DispatcherType"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    <giant stack trace omitted for brevity>
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**Why?** What's the fix? If one of the transitive dependencies is signed, how do I tell which one? Is there a way to specify unsigned versions of all the transitive deps? Is there another issue going on here, or a better solution?

Comment: Add your output of `mvn dependency:tree` to the question.  There's likely a conflict in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth. I had a similar problem and got rid of it by removing a redundant servlet-api I had in my path (javax.servlet servlet-api 2.3 provided).

I was able to run the tests from command line (in my case sbt), but when I ran them from Intellij they crashed.